# Virtual machine won't connect to the internet using bridged adapter on virtualbox

Tags: linux, networking, kali-linux, bridge

I have a Kali Linux machine up and running in VirtualBox using the bridged adapter.

My settings in VirtualBox:

- Attached to: Bridged Adapter
- Name: Qualcomm Atheros AR5BWB222 Wireless Network Adapter
- Adapter Type: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (8240EM)
- Promiscuous Mode: Allow All
- Cable Connected: Checked

Kali Linux `ifconfig`:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.244  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 2xx:xxxx:xxxx:8xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:6xxx:xx7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 xxx::xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 08:00:27:b9:25:a4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 32  bytes 3577 (3.4 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 66  bytes 5446 (5.3 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

It's really weird because my Kali Linux machine gets an ipv4 address assigned, but can't really ping, update or browse the web.

EDIT:

`ip route` of my Kali Linux Machine

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.244 metric 100
```

I tried pinging Google, but no results.
However, pinging through ipv4 works (pinging my host machine + default gateway)

Comment: 1. Please add output of `ip route` to your question. 2. Are you using IPv4 or IPv6 for your Internet access?

Comment: Can you ping the gateway/router, both with IPv4 and IPv6?

Comment: @roaima Job done! And concerning question 2, it's IPv6, if you look at my `ifconfig` you'll see that there's 3 inet6.

@dirkt I can ping my default gateway and my host machine with IPv4, how do you ping the gateway with IPv6? Is it using `ping -6 192.168.0.1` ? If so, no I can't ping through. However a normal `ping 192.168.0.1` works which i think is IPv4.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "_can't really ping [...] the web_"? What do you get if you try the following two commands? `ping -c1 -w2 8.8.8.8` and `ping -c1 -w2 bbc.co.uk`? If the first works and the second fails then you have Internet connectivity but your DNS is broken. If both fail then I can't help you further.

Comment: @roaima when I said _"can't really ping [...] the web"_ I meant that if i try `ping google.com` it won't go through. About those commands you told me to do, `ping -c1 -w2 8.8.8.8` returns a `2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1016ms` while `ping -c1 -w2 bbc.co.uk` didn't show anything so i had to CTRL+C (because it'll time out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time you can't bridge a wireless adapter. See [the VirtualBox forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=56236) for precise details.

Answer (score 0):

For VirtualBox bridging to work, on Debian/Ubuntu you need to have `bridge-utils` package installed